# Clicking on "Disable Maven nature" does nothing

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I cloned a project from Git and tried to convert it to a Maven project where I got the error saying "An internal error occurred during "Enabling Maven Dependency Management". I found a solution which says to disable maven nature and run mvn eclipse:clean to solve the issue. However, when I click on disable maven nature, nothing happens. There's no change at all. I still ran the mvn eclipse:clean command from terminal anyway but that didn't solve the issue.

What could be the reason that the disable maven nature button is not working?

Comment: After an internal error, always restart Eclipse.  Also, don't use eclipse goals with maven, use the "m2e" plugin.

Comment: If you right-click the project and choose _Maven > Disable Maven Nature_ and do a _Refresh_ (F5), in the project icon the 'M' will disappear and there will be no more project _Maven_ right-click submenu. If you get an internal error, make sure your Eclipse version is up to date. When the problem remains, report it to Eclipse assuming it has not been reported yet (and don't forget the full error message and a description how to reproduce it; which also applies to Stack Overflow questions).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357557/what-is-an-internal-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it